# Angular 2 rc.2 issue: Internal Error: couldn't find an animation entry for on

Tags: angular, systemjs, jspm

I am getting the following issue since I upgraded to angular 2 **rc.2** (from rc.1):

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Internal Error: couldn't find an animation entry for on
    at resolvePromise (zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:538)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:523)
    at zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:571
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:356)
    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (ng_zone_impl.js:38)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:355)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:256)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:474)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:426)BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.js:81ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.js:56(anonymous function) @ application_ref.js:229schedulerFn @ async.js:113SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:168SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:123Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:79Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:56Subject._finalNext @ Subject.js:125Subject._next @ Subject.js:117Subject.next @ Subject.js:76EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:94NgZone._zoneImpl.ng_zone_impl_1.NgZoneImpl.onError @ ng_zone.js:43NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:68ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:327Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:233_loop_1 @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:487drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:426
zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Internal Error: couldn't find an animation entry for on ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: BaseException {message: "Internal Error: couldn't find an animation entry for on", stack: "Error: Internal Error: couldn't find an animation …l (http://localhost:8080/main-bundle.js:12157:10)"}message: "Internal Error: couldn't find an animation entry for on"stack: "Error: Internal Error: couldn't find an animation entry for on↵    at new BaseException (http://localhost:8080/main-bundle.js:69665:21)↵    at eval (http://localhost:8080/main-bundle.js:10345:19)↵    at Array.forEach (native)↵    at bindAndWriteToRenderer (http://localhost:8080/main-bundle.js:10309:16)↵    at Object.bindRenderInputs (http://localhost:8080/main-bundle.js:10389:5)↵    at ViewBinderVisitor.visitElement (http://localhost:8080/main-bundle.js:10947:25)↵    at ElementAst.visit (http://localhost:8080/main-bundle.js:12058:22)↵    at eval (http://localhost:8080/main-bundle.js:12158:27)↵    at Array.forEach (native)↵    at Object.templateVisitAll (http://localhost:8080/main-bundle.js:12157:10)"__proto__: Errorconstructor: BaseException(message)toString: ()__proto__: ObjectconsoleError @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:461_loop_1 @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser:426
```

Can anyone please provide advice?

edit:

Here is my **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "bignibou-client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "bignibou-client",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf dist && tsc -p ./tsconfig.json",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "jasmine": "^2.4.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "jspm": "^0.16.34",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-cli": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jspm": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^0.4.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-systemjs": "^0.13.0",
    "karma-typescript-preprocessor": "^0.1.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.11.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "protractor": "^3.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "tslint": "^3.7.4",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^0.8.1"
  },
  "jspm": {
    "registry": "npm",
    "directories": {
      "test": "test"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.2",
      "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.2",
      "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.2",
      "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.2",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.2",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.2",
      "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.2",
      "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
      "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.2",
      "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.12",
      "angular2-moment": "^0.8.0",
      "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
      "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@^0.1.21",
      "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
      "less": "github:aaike/jspm-less-plugin@^0.0.5",
      "moment": "^2.13.0",
      "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.17",
      "ng2-translate": "^2.1.0",
      "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
      "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
      "systemjs": "0.19.27",
      "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "plugin-typescript": "babel-core@^5.8.24",
      "plugin-typescript-runtime": "babel-runtime@^5.8.24",
      "typescript": "^1.8.10"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.12",
    "angular2-moment": "^0.8.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.17",
    "ng2-translate": "^2.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Comment: Is your code using animation in any way?

Comment: I am sorry. Yes my code was using animations: `animate-on="SIGNIN_ERROR"`

Comment: I removed that directive and it now works.

Comment: Weird, what should it do?

Comment: That was a leftover from an angular 1 app...